# C++ error when inserting a pair into vector of maps

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012

I'm trying to create a graph using a vector of maps. I am actually looking at the code from a book and trying to enter it into visual studios 2012 so I can mess around with the graphs. But for some reason it will not allow me to add a pair to vector. code below

creating the vector

```
//vector that holds a map of all adjacent vertices
vector<map<int, int> > adjList;
```

constructor for the graph class

```
Graph::Graph(int n){
    map<int, int> element;
    adjList.assign(n, element);
}
```

adding items into the vector

```
int v1 = e.v1;
int v2 = e.v2;
int weight = e.weight;
//add the first vertix the edge connects to intto the adjList
adjList.insert(make_pair(v1, weight));
//add the second vertix the edge connects to into the adjList
adjList.insert(make_pair(v2, weight));
```

errors I'm getting from visual studios 2012 when trying to compile

```
Error   1   error C2661: 'std::vector<_Ty>::insert' : no overloaded function takes 1 arguments  c:\users\elliot\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\graph\graph.cpp   25  1   Project1
Error   2   error C2661: 'std::vector<_Ty>::insert' : no overloaded function takes 1 arguments  c:\users\elliot\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\graph\graph.cpp   27  1   Project1
```

Comment: You are not inserting proper stuff into vector. You have a vector of maps, not vector of pairs. Change it to vector of pairs.

Comment: For the structure you have, first you have to put some maps in the vector, then you can insert pairs into individual maps in the vector.

Comment: ahhh so I need a default empty maps in the vector then add the pairs to each map?

Comment: oops sorry looking back at my graph constructor I actually create the maps already. added constructor to the post

Comment: I don't think you understand that code enough. make_pair makes a pair. You have a vector of maps. You cannot append a pair as a member of something that is supposed to hold maps as members.

Comment: Yes I'm confused about this combination of data structures and how they represents a graph. This method is suppose to be an adjacency list but I don't see the connection of vertices and edges. I actually think that each position N in the vector refers to each vertex and the maps represent each edge coming off that vertex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I thought I could make it clear in the comments, but let's make it more detailed. You have a vector of maps. You are trying to insert a pair of some values into a vector of maps. That is, of course, not possible (this ain't python). What you should and could do is something like this:

```
adjList[0].insert(make_pair(v1, weight));
```

or any other index you need to insert something at.

Check [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/insert/) out.

What I'm guessing is the following. Your every node is a number (it's id is an integer). So, with that number, you index a vector and get it's adjacency list. Adjacency list is a map. Each entry in the map is id of another neighbour and probably the length of the edge. So for example, if you want neighbours of node with ID 3, you would ask for adjList[2] (they are probably indexed from 0) and get a map of it's neighbours.

Comment: Ya that makes sense. so to insert an edge e that connects to vertex v1 and v2 I should do this adjList[v1].insert(make_pair(v2,weight) and also adjList[v2].insert(makepair(v1,weight). Thank you very much I have had my aha moment!

Comment: Thanks for helping me through that one haha! :)

Comment: i think this wont work, you cannot insert `std::pair<int, int>` where one needs a `std::map<int, int>`

Comment: you are inserting pair into a map. Map is located by index. check the link I put in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The `insert` member function takes two parameters: a position, and a value.  If you don't care about specifying a position, then just use the `push_back` function.  You may have other issues, such as type issues, but this is your immediate problem.

You shouldn't assume that you compiler is speaking gibberish.  It told you exactly what was wrong:

> no overloaded function takes 1 arguments

Take a quick trip to a [handy reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/insert/) to see that it was right:

```
iterator insert (const_iterator position, const value_type& val);
iterator insert (const_iterator position, size_type n, const value_type& val);  
template <class InputIterator>
iterator insert (const_iterator position, InputIterator first, InputIterator last); 
iterator insert (const_iterator position, value_type&& val);
iterator insert (const_iterator position, initializer_list<value_type> il);
```