# How do I insert a pair into a specific position of vector?

Tags: c++

I am trying to make an adjacency list for a tree using pairs and vectors. However, I am running into a few problems when trying to implement it. This is a visualization of what I am trying to accomplish - a vector of pairs.

[image: This is a visualization of what I am trying to accomplish]

This is my current code, based on the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17848955/c-error-when-inserting-a-pair-into-vector-of-maps)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

const int MAXN = 5000;


//Define main variables
int N, Q, pi, qi, ri;
vector<pair<int, int>> adj[MAXN];

int main(){

  //Read Input
  ifstream fin("mootube.in");
  ofstream fout("mootube.out");

  fin >> N >> Q;
  for(int i=0; i<N; i++){

    fin >> pi >> qi >> ri;
    pi--;qi--;

    adj[pi].insert(make_pair(qi, ri));
    adj[qi].insert(make_pair(pi, ri));
  }

  return 0;
}
```

After declaring vector `adj` with a maximum space of 5000, I am iterating through some input to construct the adjacency list. I believe the problem I am facing is with how I insert the pairs into the vector.

When I try the above code, I am met with an error that says

```
error: request for member 'size' in 'adj', which is of non-class type 'std::vector<std::pair<int, int> > [5000]'
```

I have also tried

```
adj.insert(adj.begin() + pi, make_pair(qi, ri));
adj.insert(adj.begin() + qi, make_pair(pi, ri));
```

Which is quickly met with the following error -

```
error: request for member 'size' in 'adj', which is of non-class type
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: *After declaring vector adj with a maximum space of 5000* -- You did not do that.  You declared an array of `MAXN` vectors.  Almost inclined to close this as a typo:  `vector<pair<int, int>> adj(MAXN);` -- Note the parentheses.

Comment: There must be a typo in the textbook you're using to learn C++. `std::vector<type> v[n]` does not declare a vector with a maximum size of `n`? Vectors don't even have a defined maximum size, of some kind. Can you briefly quote what your C++ textbook says about this subject matter, in order to clear up this confusion?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Looking at the image, it is intended. The wording in the question following it is just wrong.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik See my comment above. The sentence "After declaring vector adj with a maximum space of 5000" is wrong, but the code matches the image.

Comment: If you want to simply insert a new pair into the vector, you should use `push_back` instead of `insert`.

Answer (score 0):

First, break down your illustration into components that are easily handled:

```
using prtype = std::pair<int, int>;
using vectPairs = std::vector<prtype>;
```

Now you want a vector of the above to represent the adjacency matrix:

```
using adjacencyType = std::vector<vectPairs>;
```

Now you want to create 5000 rows of the adjacency matrix;

```
adjacencyType adj(5000);
```

Then in the `main` function, you call `push_back`, assuming `pi` and `qi` are in bounds:

```
adj[pi].push_back(make_pair(qi, ri));
adj[qi].push_back(make_pair(pi, ri));
```

The above adds data to row `pi` and `qi` of the adjacency matrix.

Alternately, you could do this if you're using a C++11 compliant compiler:

```
adj[pi].push_back({qi, ri});
adj[qi].push_back({pi, ri});
```